# SQL Server 2008 R2 how to secure master key password in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, encryption, reporting-services

We have reports in SSRS and we are using SPs as a data source. We are using Master Key encryption for some tables. Below is the sequence we are following right now while writing SP:

- OPEN MASTER KEY DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'some password'
- SP SQL Statements
- CLOSE MASTER KEY;

The problem area is that we don't want to store decryption password in SP nor we want to send it through param as it can be intercepted by profiler.

I have already evaluated some of the concepts like using "With Encryption" but it is not secure (a user with proper db roles can break it easily). I also tried calling the above sequence from within the rdl file by changing DataSource “Query Type” to “Text”, but unfortunately SSRS uses sp_executesql to run parameterized queries and it gets revealed in profiler.

Any thoughts on above is highly appreciable. Please let me know in case anybody wants more information.

Comment: "A user with proper db roles ...", "profiler" - this is a people issue, not a technology one. Stop granting people you don't trust such wide ranging permissions.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - I totally agree, but this is the requirement. Any thoughts if this is still possible...

Comment: You could always Crypto with Rijndael keys in your application's code and use DB encryption on top of that.